# What does caret dot (^.) mean?

Tags: pascal

What does the below Pascal code mean?

```
p^.rlink=q
q^.llink=p
```

Comment: The assignment operator in pascal is ':=', not '='. '=' is a boolean operator that tests for equality: '==' in the C language world.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pascal operator `^.` is similar to operator `->` in C and C++.

It dereferences the pointer (in your case, `p` should be defined as `var p: ^type`) and accesses a variable in the record, in this case, `rlink` and `llink`.

Answer (score 4):

When caret (^) appears after a pointer variable it dereferences the pointer, that is, it returns the value stored at the memory address held by the pointer. So in your case I suppose that `p` is a pointer to a record that has `rlink` property and `q` is a pointer to a record that has `llink` property. These properties are also pointers to the same structure, because `p` and `q` are then assigned to them. I suppose that this structure represents a binary tree data type with left and right nodes.

Comment: +1 on the general answer, but I would assume that to be a doubly linked list and the update of pointers after adding a node. Note that `p^.rlink^.llink` is actually `p` which is a propertly found in doubly linked lists and not trees.

Answer (score 3):

A likely possibility is that p and q are elements in a [doubly-linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly-linked_list), often called a bi-directional linked list. Those two statements are attaching them together, with p on the "left" and q on the "right". An equivalent in C/C++ would be:

```
p->rlink = q;
q->llink = p;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `^`'s follow a pointer, and the `.` access a member of a record. So these lines are probably rearranging the links in a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

p and q appear to be pointers.  They point to a record variables which have respectively (or probably both), a rlink and llink  (guessing right link and left link).

This snippet is probably used in the context of a graph or maybe a linked list of sorts.

The caret (^) operator, in Pascal, is the dereference opertator which enables one to access the variable content not the the pointer.

The direct equivalent in C language would be

```
(p*).rlink=q
(q*).llink=p
```

but of course this would typically be expressed as

```
p->rlink=q
q->llink=p
```

with C's -> operator which does a deferencing and member access in one step.