# Unknown syntax in IBM research paper

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, syntax, hashmap, pseudocode

I'm reading a research paper *High Performance Dynamic Lock-Free Hash Tables
and List-Based Sets (Maged M. Michael)* and I don't understand this pseudo-code syntax that's being used for examples.

Specifically these parts:

```
〈pmark,cur,ptag〉: MarkPtrType;
〈cmark,next,ctag〉: MarkPtrType;
```

```
nodeˆ.〈Mark,Next〉←〈0,cur〉;
if CAS(prev,〈0,cur,ptag〉,〈0,node,ptag+1〉)
```

Eg. (page 5, chapter 3)
[image]

**UPDATE:**

- The `ˆ.` seems to be a Pascal notation for dereferencing the pointer and accessing the variable in the record (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814936/8524584).
- The `←` arrow seems to be a Haskell like *do notation* operator for assignment, that assigns the result of an operation to a variable. This is a bit strange, since the paper is nearly a decade older than Haskell. It's probably some notation that Haskell also borrowed from. (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation#Translating_the_bind_operator)
- The `〈a, b〉` is a mathematical vector notation for an inner product of a vector (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html)

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own question. I second "the borrow direction" between *pseudo code* and [APL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)#Design) (and, almost a quarter of a century later, Haskell). I doubt inner product is intended; I take it to be an ad-hoc list notation similar to Python where the braces can be dropped more often than not as in `low, high = 2, 8`.

Comment: @greybeard nice find on the APL relation to the `←` operator. Regarding the dot product syntax, it seems unlikely to actually being a dot product, since there's more than two elements in the vector. I'm not sure I understand you on the ad-hoc list notation. Could you give me an example in Python?

Comment: Um, `low, high = 2, 8` was the [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) example and is the same as `low, high = [2, 8]` or `[low, high] = [2, 8]` and almost the same as `low, high = (2, 8)`

Comment: (`nice find` Whoever has own memories from the 60ies hasn't been *there*.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wide angle bracket notation seems to be either an ad-hoc list notation or manipulation of multiple variables on a single line (thanks @graybeard for pointing it out). It might even be some kind of tuple.

This is what `〈pmark,cur,ptag〉: MarkPtrType;` would look like in a C like language:

```c
MarkPtrType pmark;
MarkPtrType cur;
MarkPtrType ptag;

// or some list assignment notation
// or a tuple
```

The `ˆ.` seems to be a Pascal notation for dereferencing the pointer and accessing the variable in the record (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814936/8524584).

The `←` arrow is an [APL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)#Design) assignment notation, also similar to the [Haskell's](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation#Translating_the_bind_operator) *do notation* operator for assignment.